# Signals and Callbacks in C?

Tags: c, events, event-handling, callback, signals

Is there any way to create callbacks and signals in C?

I can use function pointer of course, but I want create a signal that can hold multiple functions i.e can bind to multiple events. Something like `boost.signals` but in C . Is there *any* way?

There are many gui libraries in C that use callbacks, how do they achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to keep a list of functions to call, and in the signal handler just iterate over that list calling every function.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef void (*event_callback_t)();

struct event_handler_node
{
    event_callback_t callback;
    struct event_handler_node *next;
};

void add_event_handler(struct event_handler_node **list_head,
                       event_callback_t callback)
{
    struct event_handler_node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct event_handler_node));

    node->callback = callback;
    if (*list_head != NULL)
        node->next = *list_head;
    *list_head = node;
}

void call_all_event_handlers(struct event_handler_node *list_head)
{
    struct event_handler_node *node;

    for (node = list_head; node != NULL; node = node->next)
    {
        (*node->callback)();
    }
}

struct event_handler_node *signal_callbacks = NULL;
void signal_handler(int signum)
{
    call_all_event_handlers(signal_callbacks);
}

void my_callback()
{
    printf("Hello from callback!\n");
}

int main()
{
    /* Add a callback to the list */
    add_event_handler(&signal_callbacks, my_callback);

    /* Set signal handler for a signal */
    signal(SIGUSR1, signal_handler);

    /* Invoke the signal handler */
    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);

    return 1;
}
```

**Note:** There is no error handling, and no freeing of allocated memory. That's left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: but I don't know how many functions will be binded to the signal handler, so I would need a dynamic array / list. I don't think there is a dynamic array in C.

Comment: Of course there is. Dynamic arrays can be very easily implemented with `malloc` and `realloc`. Also, there's nothing stopping you from writing your own linked list implementation (which would be preferable here, in my opinion).

Comment: @Daniel and if you're using a unix-based system chances are you can use `<sys/queue.h>`

Comment: @IntermediateHacker Updated my answer with a working program.

Answer (score 3):

Like Joachim said, you should save list of function pointers. There is no native dynamic array in C, but you can implement it yourself:

```
struct list {
 void (*func)(void);
 struct list *next;
} *cb=NULL;
void add_callback(void (*f)(void)) {
 struct list *newCallback=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
 newCallback->func=f;
 newCallback->next=cb;
 cb=newCallback;
}
void call_callbacks() {
 struct list *t=cb;
 while (t) {
  (*(t->func))();
  t=t->next;
 }
}
```

Comment: @coder02 You've proposed an edit to change the variable from `new` to `newCallback` and to cast the malloc result - i.e. so that it'll compile with C++ compiler. Note that the code as-is is valid C. However IMO it's worth avoiding variables called `new` anyway - IIRC some compilers reject it as a reserved name anyway.